# c++ questions , counting alphabet in a file

Tags: c++

I need to program that counts alphabet in a txt file. I somehow completed how program count the alphabet but, the thing is I have to generate the number of both lower case and upper case.
here is my code

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int countChars(char lowletter);
int countChars2(char upletter);
int countChars3(char total);
int main()
{
    
    char lowletter;
    char upletter;
    char total;
    
    cout << "CHARACTER\t\tHOW MANY TIMES" << endl;
    for (lowletter = 'a'; lowletter <= 'z'; lowletter++)
    {
        cout  <<lowletter<<"\t\t\t"<< countChars(lowletter) << "times" << endl;

    }
    for (upletter = 'A'; upletter <= 'Z'; upletter++)
    {
        cout << upletter << "\t\t\t" << countChars2(upletter) << "times" << endl;

    }
    

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
int countChars(char lowletter)
{
    ifstream stream;
    char character;
    int count = 0;

    stream.open("Source.cpp");
    stream.get(character);

    while (!stream.fail())
    {
        if (character == lowletter)
            count++;
        stream.get(character);

        
    }

    
    stream.close();

    return count;
}
int countChars2(char upletter)
{
    ifstream stream;
    char character;
    int count = 0;

    stream.open("Source.cpp");
    stream.get(character);

    while (!stream.fail())
    {
        if (character == upletter)
            count++;
        stream.get(character);


    }


    stream.close();

    return count;
}
```

If I run this it gives me the number of lower letter and upper letter seperately , I want to sum of these two data and print it again how can I do this?

Comment: You can store the result of the function in two variables and you can add those variables.

Comment: If you mean that "You want to count 'a' and 'A' as same", then you should probably provide the **actual arguments** in their lower case format using ```to_lower(character)```. Hope, it helps.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Yes that's what I have been trying to do . like I tried to find how the data is stored in for loop .. I created new function that adds up those two result but it didn't work . I don't know how to define new function that can add up those two results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, you're printing out the results to the console. Instead you could declare an array with 26 positions for each letter.

e.g:-
`uint32_t character_count[26];`

C++ standard leaves the implementation details of the character encoding open. So, different systems might have their own character encodings.

However, In most systems C++ characters are represented in Unicode which is [consistent](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarg/unicode_standard.htm) with ASCII (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii). So `'a' = 97, 'b' = 98 .. 'z' = 122` for lower case letters. `'A' = 65, 'B' = 66 .. 'Z' = 90` for upper case letters.

Now you can count within the loop. Note that instead of subtracting 97 or 65 from letter, we can use the character value to avoid the problem of the underlying character encoding (given that the encoding increases in an ascending manner). (Thank you [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) for pointing out).

```
uint32_t character_count[26];
char letter;

for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
  character_count[letter - 'a'] = countChars(letter);
}

// repeat for upper case letters
for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) {
  character_count[letter - 'A'] += countChars(letter); 
}
```

### Runtime Complexity

Your program can be improved to run faster. Although the above algorithm works, it is not efficient.

For each character you are going through the whole file "Source.cpp" 26 times. Since you are doing again for upper case letters, you are going through the file 52 times.

- Instead you can load the file once and go through each character.
- First we can check whether it's upper / lower case by looking at the ascii range. By doing so, we can avoid running two separate loops for upper and lower.
- Then we can subtract 97 or 65 accordingly to find the array position.
- Finally, we can increment the array position.

Comment: Thank you @user4581301 for your valuable comments. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Slight correction: Most systems still default to ASCII, not Unicode. This is probably because of all the infrastructure built around 1 byte `char`. Plus there is there is no one encoding for Unicode. Insane, eh?  I would also replace *Then we can subtract 97 or 65 accordingly to find the array position.* with *Then we can subtract 'a' or 'A' accordingly to find the array position.* to remain consistent.

Comment: Note: The universal, works anywhere answer is to use something like `std::map<char, int> frequency;` then you can `frequency[letter]++;` to do the count. It's slower, but it's character encoding agnostic. But since you can work your whole coding career and see nothing but ASCII these days, an array's the best place to start.